# How to get the SHA1 fingerprint certificate in android studio

Tags: android

SHA1 for Debug

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

SHA1 for Release

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "/home/compe18/Keystore folder/keystore.jks" -alias keystore Alias Name -storepass password -keypass password
```

Note: storepass and keypass are applicaiton Keystore password, keystore = keystore path,alias = Key alias Name (name used at the time of creating Keystore).....

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: To get sha1 for map it will be usefull...

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the following code:

```
try {
         PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                           "yourpackagename", 
                            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
         for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                  }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}    
}
```