# Firebase AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER Sign in issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have used Firebase AuthUI, this code in my code

```
mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null){
                    onSignedInInit();
                } else {
                    onSignedOutCleanUp();
                    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

                AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder config1 = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER);
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder config2 = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER);
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder config3 = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER);
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder config4 = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER);

                providers.add(config1.build());
                providers.add(config2.build());
                providers.add(config3.build());
                providers.add(config4.build());

                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setProviders(providers)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
```

at this time when I run the App from Android Studio by clicking 
[image] button, the AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER Sign in is working fine as can be seen below

[image]

But when I Generate Signed AKP as release/debug apk, the AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER Sign in is not working as can be seen below

[image]

at this point Sign in activity is freezes and shows Toast *Sign in cancelled...* Back button is pressed and solution to this issue please...

Comment: Did you add the SHA-1 of the signing certificate to the Firebase console?

Comment: Maybe using SHA-1 of debug certificate.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Yes I've added __SHA-1 of the signing certificate to the Firebase console__ sorry for late reply!

Comment: @Toris How can I check if I'm using __SHA-1 of debug certificate__

Comment: @ArshadAli See your config file (google-services.json). certificate_hash of oauth_client is the SHA-1 key. To get SHA-1 key of certificate, this may helps. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689095/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio

Comment: To get SHA-1 key for the signed apk , command is like this. `(path of jre)\bin\keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias (key alias) -keystore (key store path)`